# A program for draw differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I need to analyze the autonomous equation  $ \ddot x +x +\alpha x^2 = 0 $ I need to analyze its flow about its critical points, can you suggest me a program in which I can draw this equation ( $\dot x $ versus  $x $) and see how it is?

Comment: Yes, a phase portrait

Comment: Here's another suggestion: http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html